# Calling a method of a class without creating object of it

Tags: java

```
class A{
    String z(){
        System.out.println("a");
        return "sauarbh";
    }
}
class B{
    A a;
    A x(){
    return a;   
    }
}
public class runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a2=b.x();
        a2.z(); // Calling A class method without creating object of it
    }
}
```

**another example**

```
class Person
   {
   private String lastName;
   private String firstName;
   private int age;
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public Person(String last, String first, int a)
      {                               // constructor
      lastName = last;
      firstName = first;
      age = a;
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayPerson()
      {
      System.out.print("   Last name: " + lastName);
      System.out.print(", First name: " + firstName);
      System.out.println(", Age: " + age);
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public String getLast()           // get last name
      { return lastName; }
   }  // end class Person
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ClassDataArray
   {
   private Person[] a;               // reference to array
   private int nElems;               // number of data items

   public ClassDataArray(int max)    // constructor
      {
      a = new Person[max];               // create the array
      nElems = 0;                        // no items yet
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public Person find(String searchName)
      {                              // find specified value
      int j;
      for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)            // for each element,
         if( a[j].getLast().equals(searchName) )  // found item?
            break;                       // exit loop before end
      if(j == nElems)                    // gone to end?
         return null;                    // yes, can't find it
      else
         return a[j];                    // no, found it
      }  // end find()
//--------------------------------------------------------------                                    // put person into array
   public void insert(String last, String first, int age)
      {
      a[nElems] = new Person(last, first, age);
      nElems++;                          // increment size
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public boolean delete(String searchName)
      {                              // delete person from array
      int j;
      for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)            // look for it
         if( a[j].getLast().equals(searchName) )
            break;
      if(j==nElems)                      // can't find it
         return false;
      else                               // found it
         {
         for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++)     // shift down
            a[k] = a[k+1];
         nElems--;                       // decrement size
         return true;
         }
      }  // end delete()
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   public void displayA()            // displays array contents
      {
      for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)       // for each element,
         a[j].displayPerson();          // display it
      }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
   }  // end class ClassDataArray
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ClassDataApp
   {
   public static void main(String[] args)
      {
      int maxSize = 100;             // array size
      ClassDataArray arr;            // reference to array
      arr = new ClassDataArray(maxSize);  // create the array
                                     // insert 10 items
      arr.insert("Evans", "Patty", 24);
      arr.insert("Smith", "Lorraine", 37);
      arr.insert("Yee", "Tom", 43);
      arr.insert("Adams", "Henry", 63);
      arr.insert("Hashimoto", "Sato", 21);
      arr.insert("Stimson", "Henry", 29);
      arr.insert("Velasquez", "Jose", 72);
      arr.insert("Lamarque", "Henry", 54);
      arr.insert("Vang", "Minh", 22);
      arr.insert("Creswell", "Lucinda", 18);

      arr.displayA();                // display items

      String searchKey = "Stimson";  // search for item
      Person found;
      found=arr.find(searchKey);
      if(found != null)
         {
         System.out.print("Found ");
         found.displayPerson();
         }
      else
         System.out.println("Can't find " + searchKey);

      System.out.println("Deleting Smith, Yee, and Creswell");
      arr.delete("Smith");           // delete 3 items
      arr.delete("Yee");
      arr.delete("Creswell");

      arr.displayA();                // display items again
      }  // end main()
   }  // end class ClassDataApp
```

As in above code i am calling z() method of class A with reference a2 without creating object of class A,As i am new to java i want to know which concept is this in java in the shown code ? for now i just know that  if we want to call a method without creating object of it we have to make that method as static .

in the second example using person reference found we are able to call displayPerson() method without null pointer exception

Comment: `static` is the keyword you're looking for.

Comment: You'll get a null pointer exception if you don't have an instance `A` in class `B`.

Comment: The above code should throw a NullPointerException **because** you never create a new A inside of B.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you're right there, but that's not the main point of the question, so I assume OP just made this code to make it compile, not to make it run.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well *maybe*, but OP does have `static void main`. Some things are a mystery.

Comment: @user3690061 Your second example has nothing to do with static. Your first example is just flawed, that's why you're getting the NPE.

Comment: That's because `Person found` is initialized later and since it's value is different than null you can call a non static method on it but you still need the reference. If you want to call a method directly from the class without any object reference to it, study the `static` keyword.

Comment: Part of a [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or maybe [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes i know use static but as in second example there is no object of person is created and it is initialized as Person found;
  found=arr.find(searchKey);,but i am able to call displayperson method ,without creating object using new keyword

Comment: `insert()` will create `Person` instance.

Comment: @user3690061 You should read your own examples more carefully, especially this line `a[nElems] = new Person(last, first, age);`.

Comment: @Tom, again, that's because `arr.find(searchKey)` will return a reference to a `Person` or `null` then you perform a null validation and call a method on an object reference. Geez...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza And what is the reason for writing that to me?

Comment: @Tom I thought you were the OP. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tom it can't be undone and I won't delete that comment...

Answer (score 6):

To call:

```
String z(){
        System.out.println("a");
        return "sauarbh";
    }
```

without the object of the class `A` the method `z` has to be static:

```
static String z(){
        System.out.println("a");
        return "sauarbh";
    }
```

So change your code as following:

```
class A{
    static String z(){
        System.out.println("a");
        return "sauarbh";
    }
}
class B{
    A a;
    A x(){
    return a;   
    }
}
public class runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         B b = new B();
         b.x();
         A.z();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
a
```

Comment: I think `A.z()` is enough if `z` is static.

Comment: To add to @TAsk comment, you should avoid calling `static` methods on references, even if they're `null` references and the code runs.

Comment: It's considered as a bad practice calling `static` methods on variables. Better just do `A.z()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes without instantiate the class if you want to call the method you should use `static` key word.

What are you doing here?

You are indirectly try to get instance of `A`. But this case you will get `NullPointerException` since you just return only a reference(variable) of `A`

```
B b = new B();
A a2=b.x();
a2.z(); // NullPointerException from here
```

NPE?

```
class B{
  A a;
  A x(){
   return a;   // you just return the reference 
   // it should be return new A();
  }
 }
```

For your edit:

Take a look at `insert()` method. It is creating `Person` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Class B method `x()` is not returning new object of A. Instead you are returning  object of Class A with null value.

```
A a; // value of a is null 
A x() {
    return a;
}
```

In runner class

```
A a2=b.x(); // b.x() will return a, which is null. so A a2=null
a2.z();    // Equivalent to null.z() throws NullPointerException
```

Make below changes in your `Class B` code:

```
class B{
    A a;
    A x(){
    return new A();// return new object of Class A;   
    }
}
```

or

```
class B{
    A a= new A(); // Initialize Class A with new object 
    A x(){
    return a;   
    }
}
```